# Switching character and keeping animations in Unity default third person controller

Tags: unity, animation, character

This is probably a ridiculous question, but I am doing a school project in Unity and am trying to create a basic game. For movement I want to use third person controller and since this is very basic I wanted to keep the default 3d model of character as well (Ethan). But since it is so colorless I had a friend of mine to color it up and then export it back to unity.
The problem is that it's a different model now and animations don't work anymore so I want to know how to correctly switch them to keep default animations? The models are the same otherwise so animations should be possible to apply.
Since nothing I tried so far didn't help I really hope someone can give me some instructions.. :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a somewhat complex thing, which there are a couple of different options.

1. You could take Ethan and color him. The "Ethan Occlusion" in ThirdPersonCharacter/Textures show this file. You can add some color to him via it. The mapping is a bit tricky to see from the file, but it could be done.
2. Load Ethan.fbx into a 3d modeling program (Blender, for instance), and use that to help color him. This will make #1 a bit easier.
3. Bring your own model. The trick with this is you need to set the bones up. Really this needs to be done in the 3d program, while bringing it into Unity and setting it up with the controller, via what's called an Avatar. Ethan's is called EthanAvatar, in the Models folder. In theory, switching the Avatar but keeping the same controller should allow you to use the same motions. If all of this is greek to you, well, let's just say it's a complex process.

If you can, I would try for #1 or #2. If you really want your friends model, then you need to go through the third step, in particular setting up the Avatar correctly.

Comment: Thanks I used your advice and will actually try #1 and #3 and see which comes out better :)